# How to stack tabs in Excel in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have an Excel file with 4 tabs,
I read these tabs using the following codes:

```html
   

 library(rio)
 library(tidyverse)
  list<- import_list("test.xlsx", setclass = "tbl")
```

I get 4 Tibbles for each tab in Excel. I want to stack these Tibbles to get one file. I don't know how to uses stack().

Here is a small sample of the data

```html
Sheet 1
ID  colour  size
12  Yellow  2
11  Red 3

Sheet 2
ID  colour  size
11  Blue    1
9   Red 1

sheet3
ID  colour  size
7   black   1
9   yellow  2

sheet 4
ID  colour  size
2   Red 1
4   Yellow  1

and the outcome is

ID  colour  size
12  Yellow  2
11  Red 3
11  Blue    1
9   Red 1
7   black   1
9   yellow  2
2   Red 1
4   Yellow  1
```

Comment: The verb "stack" could mean several things in the context of dataframes and such, many of them having nothing to do with the function `utils::stack()`. Please use `dput` to provide the the two rows (and limit the columns if they are not necessary) of your four tibbles, and then please show what you expect the output to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below.

BTW, it's generally bad practice to name an object the same as a base R function, especially something as heavily-used as `list`. I'm using `L` here to indicate the object that contains your four frames.

```r
do.call(rbind, L)
#   ID colour size
# 1 12 Yellow    2
# 2 11    Red    3
# 3 11   Blue    1
# 4  9    Red    1
# 5  7  black    1
# 6  9 yellow    2
# 7  2    Red    1
# 8  4 Yellow    1

### equivalent, if you're already using `dplyr` or `data.table`
dplyr::bind_rows(L)
data.table::rbindlist(L)
```

---

Data as provided by the output of `dput(L)`.

```r
L <- list(structure(list(ID = 12:11, colour = c("Yellow", "Red"), size = 2:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)), structure(list(ID = c(11L, 9L), colour = c("Blue", "Red"), size = c(1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)), structure(list(ID = c(7L, 9L), colour = c("black", "yellow"), size = 1:2), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)), structure(list(ID = c(2L, 4L), colour = c("Red", "Yellow" ), size = c(1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)))
```